# Autoreload failed. ModuleNotFoundError : spec not found for the module

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
[autoreload of R17_Plot_profiles failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jdrevon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 244, in check
    superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
  File "/home/jdrevon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py", line 378, in superreload
    module = reload(module)
  File "/home/jdrevon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 314, in reload
    return importlib.reload(module)
  File "/home/jdrevon/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 168, in reload
    raise ModuleNotFoundError(f"spec not found for the module {name!r}", name=name)
ModuleNotFoundError: spec not found for the module 'R17_Plot_profiles'
]
```

This problem occurs in Python 3.7 on Spyder when I modify part of my code and I press F9 to execute some parts of it. Even if I execute my main python file which load every sub-python .py codes I have this error message. However, It does not stop the code from running but the file didn't save the modifications made. This is the first times it happens since I imported the 'R17_Plot_profiles.py' python file.

However in the case where I execute the main profile, I have the previous message but I have also the following one :

```
Reloaded modules: reconstruct, R2_Spice_Kernels, R4_Offset_Correction, R5_State_Vectors_twoway_v2, R6_Foot_Print, R7_Framework_Conversion,  
R8_BendAng_ImpParam_up, R8_BendAng_ImpParam_dn, R9_Avg_BendAng_ImpParam, R10_Altitude_above_Ellipsoid, R11_Refractivity_and_Bending_Radius_v2, 
R12a_Electron_Density_up, R12b_Electron_Density_dn, R12_Electron_Density_avg, R13_Neutral_Number_Density, 
R14_Pressure_and_Temperature, R16_Errors, R17_Plot_profiles,
R3_Read_L2_Data_v2
```

So I don't know how to solve the autoreload problem. I've tried to downgrade my IPython version to 7.5 like some people tried and succeed but for me It doesn't change anything.

Edit : It's important to notice that if I restart the kernel, the first execution do not show the error message until I modify directly the python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did few modifications yesterday and it seems to be solved. Since the error occurence started to be random at some points, i'm not sure for 100% but it can maybe solve the issue.

The problem could be came from the use of `os.chdir` function, I replaced it by specifying the entire path to save my figures until to go to the path using `os.chdir` and then save my figures in it.

It can maybe produce some conflicts of path and repository to find the python script which is no longer in the path where the script is currently working and therefore can't find it in order to save the modifications.

I keep you informed if at some point the error comes back but for now after some trials the error didn't show up anymore.

Comment: This solution worked for me. The error was produced when elements which were directly linked to a change of the path with `os.chdir`, different from the original one, in which the code was currently working, was modified. Since I used the method above, the errors disappeared.